# HTML: Images having same width

Tags: html

I want to have a page with 3 (for example) images, placed horizontally and all having same width (though the actual image sizes may differ). They can change the image height according to the image ratio, no restriction on that.

So I am using a table with width = 100% [table width="100%"]. Inside that table, there is one row with three columns (td), each 33% [td style="width:33%;"]. Each table description has one image, width of which I have specified as [img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}a.jpg" 80% style="width:80%;"] to ensure that each image occupy 80% of the 1/3 of the screen width.

It is working fine with Mozilla, but in Chrome, when hitting refresh, images are becoming very very small, but while hitting enter over the browser url, it's working fine. Basically it's not taking the table width as 100%, which I can figure out by using border attribute.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using css to style the images instead of html?

Using the float property to align divs horizontally is fairly easy, and then you an apply percentages to each div and image, meaning it will re-size when ever the window size changes.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I dont want to use CSS, because I want to keep the page as simple as I can. Because users have something to do with source code, so they need a very simple 'view source'